# What was the purpose behind the metal object Forest Whitaker rubbed on Jake Gyllenhaal's face in Southpaw?

Tags: props, southpaw

In [Southpaw](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1798684/), Forest Whitaker rubs a metal object on Jake Gyllenhaal's cheek to do some sort of first aid I presume. I think it could be metal chilled in iced water to reduce blood flow. Is that correct? Or, what was it really? This action also included cotton swaps (or strips) and applied pressure with perhaps an ointment like Vaseline to assist blood clotting between boxing rounds.

Comment: If you're not interested in the movie elements, shouldn't this be on Health or Physical Fitness?

Comment: I'd rather modify the question to match the forum. I just don't want to spoil the storyline since this film is still in theaters.

Comment: one who is answering can use spoiler tag for movie plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device in film is called an [Eye Iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_Iron). Its purpose is to reduce swelling, and yes it is cooled on ice prior to application. The job of the guy that does this in the fighting ring is called [Cutman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutman).

Comment: Also known as an enswell.